# Setup rabbitmq deployment with two replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I need to setup rabbitmq deployment inside a kubernetes cluster.

The rabbitmq is not accessible from outside so I just need a clusterIP service rather than a load balancer.

I went through the documentation for Statefulset. But It talks about setting up a rabbitmq cluster i.e one master and two worker nodes.

Why can't I just have a rabbitmq deployment with two replicas and persistent volume?

This is my current config file for deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-depl
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
    - name: rabbitmq
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5672
```

What is the right way to integrate rabbitmq inside a k8s cluster?

How can I use statefulset for persistent data of rabbitmq?

What is the difference between setting up cluster and using just deployment in case of rabbitmq?

Comment: That's quite a lot of questions, for starters you should not go for even numbers of replicas if you want HA, because the voting won't work if one replica is down: 1 is not a majority when there are 2 voters. Check rabbitmq Operator and related documentation please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the documentation of statefulset and deployment you might be able to clear the doubt but no worries.

here we go

```
StatefulSet is the workload API object used to manage stateful applications.

Manages the deployment and scaling of a set of Pods, and provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods.

Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.
```

If you want persistent data you should be using the stateful set for applications like RabbitMQ and Elasticsearch.

Rabbitmq manages the nodes by node name : https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#node-names for that it mainly uses the stateful sets.

You can run the single node RabbitMQ but in that case there will be no HA.

There is a difference like in cluster you get HA if you want to implement just mirroring of the queue you can also do it.